# Entity Framework 6 (code first) using child collection foreign key without the parents primary key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I really think I am missing something here that's probably really simple that's not jumping out at me.

I have these objects and I am trying to join a parent object to a child collection but not necessarily using the parent's primary key.  In sql I can do this pretty easily, but it's bugging me why this cannot happen using code first.  I am trying to join CompetitorMatchInformation to BrandSkuPricing by the ErpSkuId.

```
public class CompetitorMatchInformation {
    [Key(), Column("MatchId")]
    public long MatchId { get; set; }

    [Column("ErpSkuId")]
    public int? ErpSkuId { get; set; }

    [Column("CompetitorId")]
    public int CompetitorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompetitorId")]
    public virtual Competitors Competitor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompetitorItemToErpSkuMatchId")]
    //[ForeignKey("ErpSkuId")]
    public virtual List<BrandSkuPricing> BrandSkuPricing { get; set; }
}

public class Competitors
{
    [Key(), Column("CompetitorId")]
    public int CompetitorId { get; set; }
    [Column("CompetitorName")]
    public string CompetitorName { get; set; }
}

public class BrandSkuPricing
{
    [Key(), Column("BrandSkuId")]
    public int BrandSkuId { get; set; }

    [Column("CompetitorItemToErpSkuMatchId")]
    public long CompetitorItemToErpSkuMatchId { get; set; }

    [Column("ErpSkuId")]
    public int? ErpSkuId { get; set; }

    [Column("Price")]
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }

    [Column("BrandId")]
    public int? BrandId { get; set; }

    [Column("BrandSourceSytemId")]
    public string BrandSourceSytemId { get; set; }

    [Column("BrandName")]
    public string BrandName { get; set; }

    [Column("BrandSkuNumber")]
    public string BrandSkuNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The Competitor comes over correctly, but the child collection not so much.  This isn't a normal scenario I know, but the underlying view for BrandSkuPricing has a relationship that's not entirely normal.

The query I am using is

```
public List<CompetitorMatchInformation> GetCompetitorMatchInfoByCompetitorItemId(long competitorItemId, int? brandId = null)
{
    var query = this.Entity.Include(x => x.CurrentChallenges).Include(x => x.BrandSkuPricing);
    var list = query.Where(x => x.CompetitorItemId == competitorItemId &&
                          ((x.CurrentChallenges.Count > 0 && x.CurrentChallenges.Any(w => !w.IsResolved)) ||
                            x.CurrentChallenges.Count == 0))
                .ToList();
    list.ForEach(l =>
    {
        if (brandId.HasValue)
        {
            l.BrandSkuPricing = l.BrandSkuPricing.Where(x => x.BrandId == brandId).ToList();
        }
    });

    return list;
}
```

And in the model builder, I have nothing.  I have tried but cannot get it to work even in the builder.  Anyway I can get the child collection to join on ErpSkuId?  I have changed the underlying view to pull in the CompetitorItemToErpSkuMatchId so it working that way, but this scenario of joining on something that isn't a key will come up for me a lot soon.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are trying to join on something other than the FK, you have to do the other style of LINQ. i.e. from a in ctx.Parent...  So you can specify the join yourself manually.

Comment: @DanielLorenz - Thanks that was it!  Finally had a chance to circle back to it.  I really tried to avoid that "other" linq style with a passion.  Guess I need to circle back and rethink that.

Comment: Heh, you and I are similar.  I don't like that style either.  I think you can use .Join style instead, but in this case, the other style is easier to read. :)